# Issue with fetching extras from intent:

Tags: java, android

I have the following broadcast receiver:

```
 mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                System.out.println("onReceive");
                final String token1 = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                System.out.println("onReceive" + token1);
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    final String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                    System.out.println("Token fetched");
                    new PostLoginWithGCM(cleanKey, token).execute();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Token null");
                }
            }
        };
```

The output is:

```
09-24 14:44:04.741 9103-9103/com.exa.exaCRM I/System.out: onReceive
09-24 14:44:04.741 9103-9103/com.exa.exaCRM I/System.out: onReceivefy6gmbUODWk:APA91bHf3PrCQmzZXnfR5LU40C7Mu1jhHenX8SvYR2OvQR6A3npXKa4NF8J-eZtHoxO7QAbTe_S94L8IttuU7ZrT5S97mucJb6EmmF92y3Hi60lrGb6cBfjDHj9fYDfaL8chion-Uyh5
09-24 14:44:04.741 9103-9103/com.exa.exaCRM I/System.out: Token null
```

So the first System.out onReceive is working fine.

Second System.out gives me the token value which I pass with the Intent.

Finally I check if my extras are null or not and to my amazement it says that my extras are null, while as I just printed the data before the null check.

This is the method responsible for generating me a token and the local broadcast:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


    try {

        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        subscribeTopics(token);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SessionManager.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(SessionManager.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }

    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(SessionManager.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    System.out.println("token before assignment" + token);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", token.toString());
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onReceive method you already have an intent as parameter.
so instead of this

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Try this

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

Comment: I understand, however how does the one differ from the other?

Comment: That it, I think. You reading the wrong extras ;) I was researching if there is a different between puttin a bundle as extra or puttin directly values as extras into the intent.

Comment: Yes this solves it, however I dont understand it still.

Comment: I think Broadcast receiver always waits for the call irrespective of whether the app is running in foreground or not. So the broadcast receiver takes the intent from the app directly.
Suppose if app is not running in foreground intent becomes null

Comment: getIntent().getExtras calls the intent of the whole class, while intent.getExtras calls the intent from the methods parameter.

Comment: In other words same broadcast receiver can be used in multiple apps but functionaliy might be different. So to do respective functionality of the respective app broadcast receiver takes the intent from respective apps directly. So you can use it directly instead of calling getIntent()